# Message Prompt Using JSP and Servlet Java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, prompt

I am trying to implement an alert prompt using Javascript and JSP at Login but I cannot seen to Succeed. So far all that I have is an error Message Which I would like to come as a prompt. Please Help. This is what I have:

Servlet Side:

```
String userValidate = logindao.authenticateUser(loginbean);
        if(userValidate.equals("SUCCESS")){
            request.setAttribute("userName", userName);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            request.setAttribute("errMessage", userValidate);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

My JSP side :

```
<td><%=(request.getAttribute("errMessage") == null)
                                    ? ""
                                    : request.getAttribute("errMessage")%></td>
```

My DAO:

```
public class LoginDao {
    public String authenticateUser(LoginBean loginbean){
        String userName = loginbean.getUserName();
        String password = loginbean.getPassword();

        Connection conn = null;
        String userNameDB = "";
        String passwordDB = "";
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        try{
            conn = db.getDbConnection();
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT USER_NAME, P_WORD, WORK_CLASS FROM USER_LOGIN "
                    + "where USER_NAME = '" + userName + "'");

            while(rs.next()){
                userNameDB = rs.getString("USER_NAME");
                passwordDB = rs.getString("P_WORD");
            }
            if(userName.equalsIgnoreCase(userNameDB)&& password.equalsIgnoreCase(passwordDB)){
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
            if(userName.equals("") || password.equals("")){
                return "Username or Password is blank";
            }
        }catch(Exception asd){
            System.out.println(asd);
        }
        return "invalid user credentials";
    }
}
```

If the cerdentials are wrong Alll I get is an error message Printed on the Page.How Can I have this as a Prompt Instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSP add the following

```
<c:if test="${not empty errMessage}">
    <script>alert("${errMessage}");</script>
</c:if>
```

I've used EL as the use of scriptlets in JSP is deprecated. The `${attr}` syntax simply pulls the value of an attribute named *attr* as test from either *page*, *request*, *session* or *application* scope in that order.

***EDIT** : (debug as)*

```
<p>errMessage is: '<%= request.getAttribute("errMessage") %>'</p>
<c:if test="${not empty errMessage}">
    <script>alert("${errMessage}");</script>
</c:if>
<% request.setAttribute("errMessage", "forced error message"); %>
<c:if test="${not empty errMessage}">
    <script>alert("${errMessage}");</script>
</c:if>
```

Comment: A blank prompt is coming every time the Page Loads. WOuld you be knowing why this is so?

Comment: @Stanley I made a typo and wasn't closing my <c:if> properly. If this doesn't solve your problem "view > source" and check what's the HTML code being generated.

Comment: When the page loads I am getting printing on the page `errMessage is: 'null'` and a blank prompt.

Comment: @Stanley. I believe you should close this question since this answers your original query about how to get the Javascript prompt you were looking for. The follow up issue seems to be related with your servlet not being able to set values for your attributes (which are coming null now) and could be better solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17502047/1237040) in your follow up question.

Comment: OK then I will close the Question and thenk you for the help.