# Remove alert from Page Load JSP

Tags: java, jsp, alert

I have a Jsp Page and The Alert Box is Loading every time the Page is Opened. I need this alert to display only if certain condition is met. Here Is My JSP. This is loading an empty alert every time the Page Loads.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="css/style.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class ="menuOption" action ="MenuServlet" method ="GET">
           <table border="0" class ="menuOption">
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Enter Menu Option<input type="text" name="menuoption" value="" /><input  type="submit" value="GO" name="gomenu" /></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <c: if test="${not empty nulloption}">
                        <script>alert("${nulloption}");</script>
                    </c:if>
                     <c:if test="${not empty invalidMenu}">
                        <script>alert("${invalidMenu}");</script>
                    </c:if>
                       <td></td>

                       <td></td>
                       <td></td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw. are you sure it's not empty?

Comment: During page load it will be empty but after getting some values from the servlet it will return a value.

Comment: invalidMenu and nulloption will only contain true or false?

Comment: Not it will either contain a String value or null

Comment: Try to use `<c: if test="${not empty nulloption.value}">` and       
`<c:if test="${not empty invalidMenu.value}">` . Also - are you sure the string is not empty when the alert shows up?

Comment: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'value'.`

Comment: I thought so, lets delete my answer. The strings are absolutely not null?

Comment: to debug this, replace nullOption and invalidMenue with a valid String "foo" and check if the alert will show up again.

Comment: not the Prompt is not coming same error as above.

Comment: Problem seems to be with your servlet doing the forward to this JSP. Please, share the servlet code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to verify `invalidMenu` contents.

```
<tr>
  <td><%= request.getAttribute("invalidMenu") %></td>
    <c:if test="${not empty invalidMenu}">
      <script>alert("${invalidMenu}");</script>
    </c:if>
  <td></td>
    <% request.setAttribute("invalidMenu", "invalid menu name"); %>
    <c:if test="${not empty invalidMenu}">
      <script>alert("${invalidMenu}");</script>
    </c:if>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your dialogue give an empty alert in this case, or one that contains "null"? If it contains "null", it's more likely an issue with your `nulloption` and `invalidMenu` properties. You said they "will either contain a String value or null". Where has these been populated from?

For instance, if they get their value from a method that's using [`String.valueOf(foo)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29), where `foo` was `null`, you'll be given a String containing the text "null", rather than one which has a value of `null`, i.e the difference between:

```
String stringWithValueOfNull = "null";
String nullString = null;
```

You can verify this in the JSP itself too, by using `c:out`:

- nullOption is equal to: `<c:out value="${nulloption}"/>`.

If it prints *"nullOptions is equal to: ."* it means that you do have a `null` or empty String. If it prints *"nullOption is equal to: null."*, you have a String with a text value of "null" & you'll need to look further back to the code which generates this value.

Comment: String nullString = null is what an empty page is returning.

Comment: @Stanley, sorry, I don't really understand your comment. What do you mean by "empty page"? Is the alert you're generating reading "null" when it pops up, or is it blank? If it is reading "null", if you print out your variables to the page (`nulloption` and/or `invalidMenu`) using `c:out`, do *they* read "null", or are they blank? You need to try to debug at what stage you're getting a value that you don't expect.

Comment: @Stanley A JavaScript alert will only read "null" if the JS variable is `null` or if a string value of "null" has been passed in. Since you're not setting a variable in the `alert()` (it's already plain text once rendered by the JSP), you must have a EL variable with a value of "null". 

You'll need to look at the code that's setting `nulloption` and `invalidMenu`. Feel free to post that if you want a further hand with debugging it.